# How to create hard link in Linux from a C program

Tags: c, linux, execvp, hardlink

We know we can create hard link in Linux using `ln file1 file2` which will make `file2` a hard link of `file1`.

However when I try to do this by using a C program, I face issues. Below is the C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ((strcmp (argv[1],"ln")) == 0 )
    {
            char *myargs[4];
            myargs[0] = "ln";
            myargs[1] = argv[3];
            myargs[2] = argv[4];
            myargs[3] = NULL;
            execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
            printf("Unreachable code\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this program with gcc I run it as below.

```
$ ./a.out ln file1 file2
ln: failed to access ‘file2’: No such file or directory
$
```

Here `file1` exists and `file2` is the desired hardlink.

Could anyone point where did I make mistake here.

Thanks.

Comment: [man 2 link](http://linux.die.net/man/2/link) could possibly be of some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the test input shown by you

```
$ ./a.out     ln      file1     file2
    ^         ^        ^         ^
    |         |        |         |
  argv[0]  ..[1]    ..[2]     ..[3]
```

in your code

```
        myargs[1] = argv[3];
        myargs[2] = argv[4];
```

should read

```
        myargs[1] = argv[2];
        myargs[2] = argv[3];
```

That said, it is always better and advisable to use the `argv[n]` after checking `argc` against `n+1`.

Comment: Thanks. Donno how i missed it!

Answer (score 11):

Shell scripting knowledge rarely transfers well to C programming. Here's `man 2 link` which you should be using instead:

```
NAME
       link - make a new name for a file

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int link(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);
```

Benefits of using the C api instead of external shell tools include a dramatic performance increase and elimination of flag injection.

Comment: int linRet = link ( argv[2] , argv[3] ) ;  if (linkRet==0) return 1 ; File *fp = fopen (argv[3], "r"); if (fp != NULL) printf (" hardlink  %s for file %s \nthanks for help,\n",argv[3],argv[2]);